# :before element with position absolute on table-cell element is relative to text node, not container

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, absolute

I'm creating an Android project using Cordova and I use a lot of tables.

I have a div with `display: table-cell` and `position: relative` that follows the usual structure of a table.

The cell has a number that should be preceded by a + or - sign that I'm trying to display with the `:before` pseudo-element with `position: absolute` and a negative `margin`. The sign depends on a data-attribute of the cell. Everything works well.

When I test it on browser, the `:before` element positions itself **relative to the text node, not the cell container**. I actually want that, but it doesn't work when I'm using it via cordova on my Xperia SP. This that case, it is positioned **relative to the cell itself, not its text** (which seems to make more sense) but thus gets aligned with the other cells. Why does it act like that?

The HTML (only the important part):

```
<div class="table skill-list">
    <div class="table-row skill">
        <div class="table-cell table-amount skill-bon" data-amount="0">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row skill">
        <div class="table-cell table-amount skill-bon" data-amount="200">200</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row skill">
        <div class="table-cell table-amount skill-bon" data-amount="15">15</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.table > .table-row > .table-cell.table-amount {
    position: relative;
}

.table > .table-row > .table-cell.table-amount:before {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    font-size: smaller;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.table > .table-row > .table-cell.table-amount[data-amount^="-"]:before {
    content: "-";
    margin-left: -15px;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

The result on Chrome:

[image] (that I want)

The result on mobile:

[image] (Xperia SP, via cordova)

Comment: Try using `left:-15px` instead of `margin-left:-15px`. It might solve your issue.

Comment: It makes the result consistent on all platforms but it's the result I don't want. @Roy

Comment: In that case use `left:0px;` then use `margin-left:-15px`. What I mean is use `left` to position the element. Then use `margin-left` to align the element as you want.

Comment: The problem is that if I use `left: 0`, the `:before` elements align, and I don't want them to. @Roy

Comment: What if you don't use `position:absolute` at all? Then it should automatically stick to the right alignment. Right? Try it out. Put no positioning.

Comment: Thought about that but my goal is to avoid the `:before` to be calculated in the positioning of the number. I use it somewhere else where the number is horizontally centered and the '+' should not impact it. @roy